# CSS file can't be recognized by HTML

Tags: html, css

I recently started learning HTML & CSS.
my issue is that HTML file doesn't recognize CSS codes, I checked everything but still, maybe you guys can help me? thanks!

My HTML file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn5Pd.png)

My CSS file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAaqK.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text, and not as images.

Comment: It might be caching issue, try a hard refresh with ctrl + shift + R.

Comment: Can you please share your output?

Answer (score 2):

Just a small spelling mistake.
You wrote "stlyesheet" instead of "stylesheet" in line 6 of the html file.

Answer (score -1):

```
HTML

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
```

Please try this